# For all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}$, are there only finitely many primes so that $\gcd(\text{ord}_p(\alpha),\text{ord}_p(\beta))=1$?

Tags: number-theory

I suspect the negation of this statement is true. I was looking at this problem for fixed $\alpha,\beta$ but that's really hard, so I wanted to prove that there is at least one pair of integers with the property. So, supposing the opposite of that: for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}$ the set of primes satisfying the property $\gcd(\text{ord}_p(\alpha),\text{ord}_p(\beta))=1$ is bounded. So we can define a function $f(n)$ to be the greatest prime with the desired property over all pairs of integers $\alpha,\beta\leq n$.

Increasing $n$ appends more pairs of integers to the numbers over which $f$ has to satisfy its definition, plus the ones that were $\leq n$, so $f$ is nondecreasing. Also for a prime $p\equiv 3 \mod 4$ we can take $\alpha\equiv -1$ and $\beta\equiv w^2$ where $w$ is a primitive root and we have $\gcd(\text{ord}_p(\alpha),\text{ord}_p(\beta))=\gcd\left(2,\frac{p-1}2\right)=1$ so $f$ is unbounded.

So for some large $n$ and any prime $p>f(n)$ we have that of the $(p-1)^2$ pairs of numbers in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ we have a forbidden square in the bottom left $(n-1)^2$ elements whose elements have to have pairwise noncoprime orders. If $p-1$ has $k$ distinct prime divisors, there are $2^{k-1}$ ways of writing it as $p-1=\theta\phi$ with $\gcd(\theta,\phi)=1$ and with a primitive root $w$ we can generate $w^\theta$ and $w^\phi$ with our property. So for each of those exponentially increasing quantity of pairs of numbers, they have to *all* conspire to be outside the forbidden square for *all* primes greater than $f(n)$. This just seems unsustainable. $k$ isn't always large, for example if $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime $k=2$ and for all we know there are infinitely many of those, however it is large often enough to be a problem.

Can we derive a contradiction from this?

---

Some computational data:

For [$(\alpha,\beta)=(2,3)$](https://oeis.org/A344202) the primes with the desired property are 683, 599479, 108390409, 149817457, 666591179, 2000634731, 4562284561, 14764460089, 24040333283 and none more up to $1752\cdot10^9$.

For $(2,5)$ the primes are 31,
601,
2593,
599479,
204700049,
466344409,
668731841,
11638603429.

For $(3,5)$, they are 13, 313, 51169, 797161, 3482851, 5096867, 12207031, 162410641, 368385827, 1001523179, 4902814883.

And for $(2,6)$, they are 5,
7,
31,
43,
135607,
153649,
270841,
1489441,
1505447,
25781083,
127236649,
558062249,
745988807,
27989941729,
29512739491,
47206579351.

Comment: Isn't $ord_p(\alpha) = ord_p(\beta) = 0$ for all but finitely many primes $p$?

Comment: @D_S Here $\text{ord}$ doesn't refer to the p-adic order. It is meant to represent the order of an element in the multiplicative group $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$.